# Is there a way to fix a compiling error for yarn start or npm start that prompts 'no such file directory, stat...'

Tags: reactjs

This error prompts

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\new project\bargains\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
 throw err;
 ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\All Users'] {
 errno: -4058,
 code: 'ENOENT',
 syscall: 'stat',
 path: 'C:\\Users\\All Users'
}
```

I believe it is a path error for how yarn or npm is installed and how it is being called to my project, but i'm unsure how to fix it. I'm sorry if this is a beginner question, but I cannot find any fix.

Comment: Try using a path without spaces in it

Comment: Obviously, make sure that the path it's trying to install on really exists.